# Android app Drawable images with 6.0 version

Tags: android, mobile

I reskinned an android app (android studio ), so I replaced all the drawable images with others ( all the sizes). When I exported my app, it worked fine with all versions exept the 6.0 android version, when I open the app with android 6.0 device, the app shows the old images, how can I fix that please ?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing the cache of your android 6.0 device from settings. It is using old images stored in cache of your device. Here's the link to clear cache of android device. [https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-clear-app-cache-and-app-d‌​ata-in-android-6-0-m‌​arshmallow/](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-clear-app-cache-and-app-d%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bata-in-android-6-0-m%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Barshmallow/)

Comment: sorry in the android studio project there is not a "bin" folder !

Comment: you haven't specified you were working on eclipse or android studio.Please edit your question.

Comment: It doesn't help , I did all your steps , the problem like I said before , it works good with all android versions , but not with the 6.0 !

Comment: Try clearing the cache of your android 6.0 device from settings. It is using old images stored in cache of your device. Here's the link to clear cache of android device.  [https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-clear-app-cache-and-app-data-in-android-6-0-marshmallow/](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-clear-app-cache-and-app-data-in-android-6-0-marshmallow/)